# accessing data members of nested struct and passing struct to function C++

Tags: c++

I have a simple problem but I need to understand the concept behind it.

- How to access data members of a 1st struct by instantiating it as pointer in 2nd struct.
- If I make data members of 1st struct as pointer then how to print out there values by accessing them e.g.

  `struct temp 
    {
     int a =5;
     float b = 6.0;
     i = &a;
     f = &b;
     int *i;
     float *f;
    };`

I am working on a complex code so I need to understand the logic behind it as how it works in-terms of memory and logic.

Thanks a lot for your time in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct temp {
int i=5;
float f=6.0;
};
struct qlt {
temp *d;

};

int sum (qlt *s)
{   
int a = s->d->i;
//   std::cout<<a;
}
int main() {
 qlt x;
//int b = ;
 std::cout <<sum(&x);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What *is* the question? Please clarify

Comment: Actually, I want to print the values of 1st struct by the help of function sum() by making an object of 1st struct as pointer in 2nd struct (qlt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qlt x;
```

This creates a `qlt` allright, but not the `d` inside it. So you have a dangling pointer (since it's also left uninitialized).

```
qlt x;
temp b;
x.d = &b;
```

this would be a C-style solution. C++ has way better ways to do it.

Forget *all* sort of pointers at this moment and use STL.

Comment: Yes, you are right so thats why its giving me segmentation fault.

Comment: Just one more thing if I make data members of 1st struct as pointers then how to print them with the other things same. like        `struct temp {
     int a =5;
     float b = 6.0;
     i = &a;
     f = &b;
     int *i;
     float *f;
     }; `

Comment: You access them with *, for example cout << a, cout << b, cout << *i.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer I have marked it as +1 also regarding 2nd part of question incase my data members of 1st struct are pointers.

Comment: I still am having issue in accessing the members values within function like `int sum (qlt *s)
{   
    int a = s->d->*i;
}`  beacuse I am still getting an error that `i` does not name a type when I make data members as pointers.

Comment: `d` is a pointer; `i` isn't. So you use -> correctly, then `i`, not `*i`.